# Generate union type from an array

Tags: typescript

I want to generate union from the `ALL_RESPONSE_TYPES` array.
Having the following code:

```js
interface MetadataAccepted {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}
interface MetadataIgnored {
  c: number;
  d: string;
  e: {
    a: string
  }
}

const ALL_RESPONSE_TYPES = [
  ['ACCEPTED', { a: '', b: 0 } as MetadataAccepted],
  ['IGNORED', { c: 0, d: '', e: {a: ''} } as MetadataIgnored],
] as const;
```

I want to create the following type:

```js
type ResponseType =
  | {
      type: 'ACCEPTED';
      metadata: {
        a: string;
        b: number;
      };
    }
  | {
      type: 'IGNORED';
      metadata: {
        c: number;
        d: string;
        e: { a: string }
      };
    };
```

I believe it should be possible to achieve this in typescript.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAJPZW) meet your needs? Your "additionally" question needs more information; surely you can just write the type you want directly; do you have some input type you want to transform?  Anyway let me know if you want me to write up an answer explaining the approach in my link, or if I'm missing something

Comment: Yup, your approach is exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: Yeah, the additionally branch of my question was to still use the array as the base, but without declaring an instance (without creating the object) and just using the interface as part of the tuple in the array (not sure, whether that's possible).

Comment: I don't understand what it means to use an array that hasn't been created.  Do you have an array *type* somewhere?  If so could you write it out?

Comment: In the additionally branch, I'm asking whether eg. something like this is possible.
```
const ALL_RESPONSE_TYPES = [
  ['ACCEPTED', MetadataAccepted],
  ['IGNORED', MetadataIgnored],
] as const;
```
(Sure this doesn't compile, but you should get the gist)

Comment: If you don't want an array at runtime, you can make an array type and transform it, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mL3rkN).  But at that point there's no need for an array type at all; you could just write out a mapping interface as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1EQKw), or just write out your type *directly* as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/WKprzw).  I'm confused about the use case if you don't have an actual array.  Should I write up the answer to the first part and you could maybe just remove the "additionally" branch? SO question posts shouldn't really have multiple questions anyway.

Comment: I like the proposed solution with the mapping interface, that's the answer to the 'additional' question. But sadly that looses the possibility to have the array of the types (I still want to have them as an array to be able to do lookups on them).
In case it's not possible to get them as array also (which I think it's not possible to get array of keys of an interface), then the first answer is right.

Comment: "possibility to have the array of the types"... I'm so very confused. Either you have an array or you don't.  Which one is it?  If you have an array we use the original proposal; if you don't, why do you need an array *type*?  I'm not sure how to proceed with this anymore.  Please consider [edit]ing to ask a single, clear, well-defined question... and then I'd be happy to post an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [mapped array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) that transforms the type of `ALL_RESPONSE_TYPES` to an array type of `type`/`metadata` objects, and then [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that type with `number` to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Like this:

```
type R<T extends readonly (readonly [any, any])[]> =
  { [I in keyof T]: { type: T[I][0], metadata: T[I][1] } }[number];
```

The `R` utility type converts an array type of pairs like `[[0, 1],[2, 3],[4, 5]]` into an array of objects like `[{type:0, metadata:1},{type: 2, metadata: 3},{type: 4, metadata: 5}]` and then indexes into it to get the union `{type:0, metadata:1} | {type: 2, metadata: 3} | {type: 4, metadata: 5}`.

And when it acts on the type of `ALL_RESPONSE_TYPES`, using [the `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html), it gives you the desired `ResponseType`:

```
type ResponseType = R<typeof ALL_RESPONSE_TYPES>;
/* type ResponseType = {
  type: "ACCEPTED";
  metadata: MetadataAccepted;
 } | {
  type: "IGNORED";
  metadata: MetadataIgnored;
 } */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-A6cw8ni8ixlSydyw5u1DPN5a6CY1GaBZ8GYgA)